# Why does Azure CDN ignore cacheControlMaxAge in my web.config?

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

I have this web.config saved in my blob. I thought Azure would then update the files on my CDN every hour, but it doesn't.

```
<configuration> 
  <system.webServer> 
        <staticContent> 
            <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="0.01:00:00" /> 
        </staticContent> 
  </system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the cache control HTTP headers for the static content is being set to private. You can validate that using Fiddler (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)

One option is to use the cacheControlCustom setting as below to set it to public.

```
<configuration> 
  <system.webServer> 
        <staticContent> 
            <clientCache cacheControlCustom="public" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="0.01:00:00" /> 
        </staticContent> 
  </system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

For my static contents served with Azure Cdn, I've set the cache-control during the uploading of the files on  the blob storage. I've used grunt for the upload process, but there are different visual tools such as cloud berry for windows, or cyber duck for Mac that can allow write the headers directly on the files once uploaded or as a rule when uploading them on a specific container. 
The rule must be: Cache controll : public, max-age: seconds.